# Authentication for all the users of a organization

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

How to do Authentication for all the users of the organization through the same public token for all the users while using Azure Devops API.

Personal access token would not work in my scenario as it's limit is max 1 year.

Comment: please elaborate what you are trying to do. Why would you want to use a single **Token** for an entire organization? Maybe have a look at [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Did you want an authentication without a lifespan limit? If so, I think it's impossible.

As far as I know, there are three authentication methods in azure devops : 1.Authenticate access with [personal access tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Forganizations%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Forganizations%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops) 2.Authorize access to REST APIs with [OAuth 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Forganizations%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Forganizations%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops)  3.Use [SSH key](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/devops/repos/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Forganizations%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Forganizations%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops) authentication

If you want to use token to authenticate when using rest api, there are only two ways to authenticate: pat and oauth2.0. However, both approaches have lifespan limitations.

In PAT, you need to choose a lifespan for your token.

In OAuth2.0 ,access tokens expire, so you'll also need to refresh the access token if it's expired.